# Galaxy s3 backup contacts google play

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, google-backup

How can I get my contacts backs from my galaxy s3 when the LCD doesn't work and the screen is pitch black ?

Comment: What has Google Play got to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would say there may not be any reason to backup your contacts because I guess its backing up automatically over your gmail account. So for verifying it why don't you try logging yourself up over the Gmail account over PC/Laptop once logged in tap over the Gmail icon and click over the contacts. I am sure all your contacts are available over there !